# Let $f(x)\geq 0$ be continuous on the interval $[a, b]$. Consider the solid of revolution by rotating the graph of $f(x)$ around the $x$-axis. Prove

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, solid-of-revolution

$1.$ Let $f(x)\geq 0$ be continuous on the interval $[a, b]$. Consider the solid of revolution by rotating the graph of $f(x)$ around the $x$-axis. Prove that its volume is

$$V=\pi \int_a^b [f(x)]^2 \, dx$$

$2.$ Prove that in the previous exercise it is possible to remove the conditions that $f(x) \geq 0$ and continuity. And that it is sufficient that the set of discontinuity points is finite.

**Attempt**

For $(1)$, Let $a\leq x\leq b$ and let $P_x$ be a plane perpendicular to $x$-axis at point $x$. We can see that a cross-section of a given solid with the plane $P_x$ is a circle of a radius $r=f(x)$. So, area of that circle is

$$A(x)=\pi r^2=\pi [f(x)]^2$$

By Cavalieri´s Principle we have that volume $V$ of that solid is

$$V=\int_{a}^{b}A(x)\, dx=\int_{a}^{b}\pi [f(x)]^2 \, dx=\pi \int_{a}^{b}[f(x)]^2 \, dx$$

Comment: Hint for (2): what changes in your proof when $f(x)<0$? Imagine the graph visually, what happens at a point wise discontinuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let each point $x_i$ in the domain of $f$ be a point on a circle of radius $f(x_i)$. The area of each circle is then given by $A_i = \pi f(x_i)^2$. The volume of the revolution is then just the sum of all these areas and given $f(x)$ is continuous, then $$V = \int_a^b{A_idx_i} = \int_a^b{\pi\cdot f(x)^2dx} = \pi\cdot\int_a^b{f(x)^2 dx}$$.
2. Assume for some $x_j$, $f(x_j) < 0$ then $A_j = \pi (-f(x_j))^2 = \pi f(x_j)^2$. Then define
   $$
   A = 
   \begin{cases}
   \pi f(x)^2 & f(x) \geq 0 \\
   \pi f(x)^2 & f(x) < 0
   \end{cases}
   =\pi f(x)^2
   $$
   Hence, $$V = \int_a^b{Adx} = \pi\cdot\int_a^b{f(x)^2}$$
   Let $J$ be the set of intervals inside $[a,b]$ in which $f$ is continuous. Then $$V = \sum_{[i, j] \in J}\int_i^j\pi f(x)^2 dx$$ As all these intervals in $J$ lie inside $[a,b]$ hence, $i \geq a$ and $j \leq b$ so it can be said,
   $$V = \sum_{[i, j] \in J}\int_i^j\pi f(x)^2 dx = \int_a^b{\pi f(x)^2 dx}$$
   Note that if $|J| = \infty$ then the sum and consequently the integral would diverge, so its important to have $|J| \in \mathbf{N}$